# Trouble importing classes from package android.hardware.camera2.impl;

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm new to Android development. I'm having trouble importing from camera2 package. 
Here is a screenshot of the failed imports. I don't understand why some of them succeeded while others not.

[image]

Really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
Thanks, but I don't think it's the problem with my minSdkVersion. 
 [image]

Comment: it's only available after api 21, you should tag your app `minSdkVersion 21` and more important your ` compileSdkVersion` should be >= 21.

Share your configuration gradle file

Answer (score 1):

The failing imports are internal to Android framework. They are not available to apps. You should be okay if you simply delete all these lines that are marked red. If your code does not compile after such cleanup, post an update with specific error messages.

Comment: Hello Cohn, thank you for your reply. Sry I didn't clarify that the imports are from a sdk file and are not modifiable. I noticed there are a number of sdk files having such failed imports in my program. I'm not sure if this is the reason causing a NullPointerException.

Comment: Now you mention null pointer. That's interesting. Can you share the full message?